# How to extract information from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the dataframe below and I want to extract some information from column A and then create other columns to add them based on their types.
Below is an example to illustrate this.

```
In [0]: df
Out[0]: 
          A                  
0 1258GA 25/01/20 TABLE 090626  038272
1 GOODIES 762088 A714816
2 TABLE AA88547 734963 GOODIES
3 WATER 02/450 FROM TOMORROW 48246
4 02H12 ALSCA 00548246B GOODIES
```

And I want to have the result below.

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
          A                               Category             Date      Hour
0 1258GA 25/01/20 TABLE 090626  038272    TABLE           25/01/20
1 GOODIES 762088 A714816                  GOODIES 
2 TABLE AA88547 734963 GOODIES            TABLE GOODIES
3 WATER 02/450 FROM TOMORROW 48246        WATER 
4 02H12 ALSCA 00548246B GOODIES           GOODIES                        02H12
```

I've tried many things but haven't got that result

Comment: for row 3, y is it not WATER FROM TOMORROW? y is it just WATER? same for row 4?

Comment: It's just an axample to explain what I want to have finally. And if I know how to do that with that example, I'm going to apply that on my real data

Comment: but the example has no comprehensible logic

Comment: That doesn't explain why `FROM TOMORROW` is missing from your expected output.

Comment: How could this be upvoted? You should not let readers *guess* what you want from a simple example. You should instead first *specify* the requirement, and then illustrate with an example. Here you missed first point :-(

Comment: Sorry, in this cas, I'm only interested by water not tomorrow

Comment: And what about `TABLE GOODIES`?? Can you explain why here you want goodies but not `FROM TOMORROW` in the next case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do that using `Series.str` methods,

### The `Series.str.extract()` returns:

> Extract capture groups in the regex pat as columns in a DataFrame.
>
> For each subject string in the Series, extract groups from the first
>   match of regular expression pat.

### The Series.str.findall() returns:

> Find all occurrences of pattern or regular expression in the Series/Index.

Here is the code snippet,

**EDIT:**

```
df["Category"] = df['A'].str.findall(r"(\b[A-Za-z]+\b)").str.join(' ')
df["Date"] = df['A'].str.extract(r"(\b[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+\b)")
df["Hour"] = df['A'].str.extract(r"(\b[0-9]+H[0-9]+\b)")
```

And output will be,

```
                                      A             Category      Date   Hour
0  1258GA 25/01/20 TABLE 090626  038272                TABLE  25/01/20    NaN
1                GOODIES 762088 A714816              GOODIES       NaN    NaN
2          TABLE AA88547 734963 GOODIES        TABLE GOODIES       NaN    NaN
3      WATER 02/450 FROM TOMORROW 48246  WATER FROM TOMORROW       NaN    NaN
4         02H12 ALSCA 00548246B GOODIES        ALSCA GOODIES       NaN  02H12
```

Comment: Is it possible to have, in Category, line n°2, TABLE and GOODIES with your code?

Comment: What do you mean category in line 2, could you plz explain in details.

Comment: I mean, in the 2nd ligne of the column Category and that what I've done by editing your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
df['A'].str.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b').str.join(' ')

0                  TABLE
1                GOODIES
2          TABLE GOODIES
3    WATER FROM TOMORROW
4          ALSCA GOODIES
```

Comment: Maybe join the resulting list into strings?

Comment: `df['A'].str.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b').str.join(' ')`